# Single Sign on Sharepoint and ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, claims-based-auth, single-sign-on

I have

1.) Sharepoint 2010 web applications with Default windows authentication.

2.) ASP.Net Application with custom authentication against Same  AD.

Now I have requirement to implement SSO among these applications.

At this point I don't want to change the Authentication mode or provider in Sharepoint web application.

In browser, If I logged in with Sharepoint web application then Asp.net application should not ask authentication and vice versa.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are MANY ways to accomplish this.  You could write your own SSO SAML provider, use a third-party, etc.  However, Microsoft seems to finally be on the ball with this in the new Windows Server 2012 R2.  2012 R2 comes with a service called the "Web Application Gateway".  With this, you would setup a new 2012 R2 server that acts as a gateway to your other web applications.  You can handle your authentication at the gateway and have it passed to each published web application.

Comment: to write our own SSO SAML provider we have to implement FBA and claim based authentication.. am I right?
but I have to go with the SP web application with Claim based enabled and integrated windows authentication...
Can u please suggest some good technical article for this?